# Combinar y sumar elementos de los objetos dentro de un array en javascript

Tags: javascript, json, array

Buen día, hay alguna forma de hacer lo siguiente?

```
[{"nombre":"Juan", "dinero":5.0},{"nombre":"Juan", "dinero":25.3},{"nombre":"Manuel", "dinero":8.3}]
```

En ese array tengo repetido al usuario "Juan", entonces lo que necesito, es convertir ese array en el siguiente:

```
[{"nombre":"Juan", "dinero":30.3},{"nombre":"Manuel", "dinero":8.3}]
```

Donde unicamente se sumo el campo de "dinero" y solo con el mismo usuario

Comment: En esta pregunta responden a algo parecido:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
  // Este es tu array inicial
    var arr = [{ nombre: 'Juan', dinero: 5 }, { nombre: 'Juan', dinero: 25.3 }, { nombre: 'Manuel', dinero: 8.3 }],
    //Y aca se va a guardar el resultado
    result = [];

    // Recorro el array elemento por elemento
    arr.forEach(function (a) {
        
        // Me fijo si el elemento que voy a cargar ya existe, si no existe, lo creo con dinero en 0
        if (!this[a.nombre]) {
            this[a.nombre] = { nombre: a.nombre, dinero: 0 };
            result.push(this[a.nombre]);
        }
        // Y luego le sumo el dinero (en el caso que ya exista, no se crea, solo se le suma el dinero)
        this[a.nombre].dinero += a.dinero;
    // Como segundo argumento de la funcion del foreach paso [] para que retorne un array.
    }, []);

    console.log(result);
```